# How to implement Motion Blur in 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any way to implement motion blur to a dragged object in 2D? There is barely any answers on that on the internet so I'm asking you guys

Comment: [Post-Processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html) -> [Motion Blur](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.1/manual/Motion-Blur.html) or [URP Post-Processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/manual/integration-with-post-processing.html) -> [Motion Blur](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/manual/Post-Processing-Motion-Blur.html)  ... shouldn't matter if 3D or 2D

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure you can use the post-processing stack to help you with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).